# PHP app crashes: child pid exits with Illegal instruction (4)

Tags: linux, centos, php, crash

I have a CentOS 6 server with Apache and PHP. I run some application and can constantly reproduce this crash. After some sequential action the app dies and the only trace I found is the following message in error_log:

```
[Tue Jan 05 16:39:45 2016] [notice] child pid 1636 exit signal Illegal instruction (4)
```

I installed the same app to a different host and it works. For this reason I think the problem is in OS or Apache configuration. What could be the reason for killing this process?

**Update 1:** Both hosts has memory_limit set to 128M

**Update 2:** Disabling SElinux does not solve the problem

**Update 3:** Update from `pcre-7.8` to `pcre-8.13` does not help

Comment: Are both hosts running the same version of PHP?  Have you tried trimming or commenting out code or using `die('got here');` testing to see where the error is occurring? Can you reproduce on demand? Does the error only occur when the code is run through an HTTP server, or can you reproduce using `php-cli`?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce on demand. PHP are different. Fails on 5.3.3 works on works on 5.5.29. It looks like out-of-memory issue, so I was not focused on PHP & Apache versions too much. I haven't tried php-cli because it's Wordpress-based plugin.

Comment: Running out of memory would not cause the error you are seeing.  How about the other questions and tests?  And a code excerpt that reproduces the issue?  Not knowing what code you have makes this nigh-impossible to speculate about where the problem lies with anything other than wide generalities.

Comment: It could be SELinux, with files not labeled correctly inside `/var/www` - http://serverfault.com/questions/642353/selinux-interfering-with-apache-php

Comment: All right. I described details here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-illegal-instruction-4?replies=1 Test case is that I get EC2 micro instance (600Mb RAM) with CentOS6.7 64bit, install a vanilla Wordpress and add this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/ Than I try to perform initial configuration of the plugin and it fails. Sources are available at https://github.com/deconf/Google-Analytics-Dashboard-for-WP

Comment: This is not SELinux. I disabled it completely and the problem persists. Thanks for suggestion anyway.

Comment: It is a reported bug in PCRE , which version of PCRE your php is using? get an updated version

Comment: `# rpm -q pcre
pcre-7.8-7.el6.x86_64` could you please share a link to this bug's page?

Comment: In both environments?

Comment: Good catch. In the good environment version is different: `$ pcre-config --version
8.36`

Comment: Update from `pcre-7.8` to `pcre-8.13` does not help. http://blog.peterfisher.me.uk/2014/06/03/upgrading-pcre/

Answer (score 5):

I suddenly started getting this same error a few days ago on a Wordpress 4 site running on PHP 5.3.3 that's been hosted at Rackspace on a virtual server for a couple of years.  It's now running CentOS 6.8 and has survived many OS and Wordpress updates --  I think we started on CentOS 5.x!

Anyway I tried upgrading PHP first (which is held by CentOS 6.x at 5.3.3) but I used the 3rd-party "remi" yum repo:

> Remi's RPM repository - Blog: 
>   http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en

that let me upgrade to PHP 5.6.22

And although that didn't fix the problem, it improved the error message.  Now the apache logs were silent (!) but /var/log/messages said this, each time I hit the Wordpress admin pages:

```
kernel: php[23199] trap invalid opcode 
  ip:7ffa1074ad60 sp:7fff8bff6268 error:0 
  in libfreeblpriv3.so[7ffa106f8000+72000]
```

and googling most of those interesting words (not so much the numbers, and quoting "libfreeblpriv3.so" since there were a lot of similar hits
for other binaries) led to this CentOS bug report and discussion:

> 010930: curl -> Illegal Instruction after centos 6.8 update - CentOS Bug
>   Tracker: http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=10930#c26717

which identified the culprit: **curl**!

The sudden onset of this problem was due to a recent curl library yum-update that (apparently) conflicts with *old* OpenStack Hypervisors (e.g. our aging Rackspace Instances, which needed to be updated years ago to their newer "flavor" of virtual machines) and whenever Wordpress tried to use curl to download something, it crashed php and took the apache process out along with it.

A comment (pretty far down the thread) nailed the fix, which worked for me:

```
# How to downgrade curl:
# (updated with corrected links after those went all 404 on me)
wget http://vault.centos.org/6.7/os/x86_64/Packages/curl-7.19.7-46.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget http://vault.centos.org/6.7/os/x86_64/Packages/libcurl-7.19.7-46.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh --oldpackage curl-7.19.7-46.el6.x86_64.rpm 
rpm -Uvh --oldpackage libcurl-7.19.7-46.el6.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y yum-plugin-versionlock
yum versionlock curl
yum versionlock libcurl
service httpd restart
```

After this, I restarted apache and it was all good again :-)

Comment: an absolute godsend of a solution

Comment: I noticed that the download links for the 2 RPM's stopped working (inside the CentOS mirror?) so I poked around a few directories up till I found this note:  http://mirror.simwood.com/centos/6.7/readme which says: 
> This directory (and version of CentOS) is deprecated [...] 
> you should use /6/ and not /6.7/ in your path [...] If you know 
> what you are doing, and absolutely want to remain at the 6.7
> level, go to http://vault.centos.org/ for packages. 
> [...] 6.7 no longer gets any updates, nor any security fix's.
I edited my answer with the "vault" links that hopefully wont change

Comment: Smart. Good find.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the last update from CentOS for the nss package. It also caused apache to panic. Here are the steps to downgrade the package:

```
export NSS_DISABLE_HW_AES=1 
yum -y downgrade nss nss-util nss-tools nss-sysinit
yum -y install yum-plugin-versionlock
yum versionlock add! nss-3.21.0-8.el6.x86_64 nss-sysinit-3.21.0-8.el6.x86_64 nss-tools-3.21.0-8.el6.x86_64 nss-util-3.21.0-2.el6.x86_64
```